# Why doesn't jQuery use $, and how can I get it do so (GLOBALLY)?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have a WordPress theme that includes jQuery, but for some reason the "$" doesn't let me call jQuery. I know I can wrap [jQuery calls in an anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371539/why-define-anonymous-function-and-pass-jquery-as-the-argument/10372429#10372429), but I have other plugins that rely on the $ working, and I don't want to modify their code.

So I need a way to make "$" work for jQuery, globally, across all JS in my site.

My theme adds jQuery with this (in functions.php):

```
function ss_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ss-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ss_scripts' );
```

So two questions:

1. Why doesn't jQuery default to the "$" when the script is added this
   way?
2. How can I make the $ use jQuery, globally, across my entire
   site?

Comment: Read here about noConflict mode in WordPress: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't jQuery default to the "$" when the script is added this
>   way?

The `$` alias has been chosen by several different libraries an alias. This causes conflict if you try to use more than one library. It is a bit ridiculous, actually-- like several major corporations all deciding to use the same phone number.

> How can I make the $ use jQuery, globally, across my entire site?

WordPress load jQuery in [noConflict mode](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to avoid the problems caused by the above foolish aliasing. You should not reintroduce those issues.

Answer (score 1):

To use `$` as the object reference, you need to do this after jQuery is included and before any other script that uses `$`:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Use at your own risk, may conflict with other code.

Technically, any jQuery plugin that relies on `$` is written incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $ use 'jQuery'.  I am not sure about your WordPress version.  For the updates with jQuery. 1. 9.  It's better to use jQuery  instead of $.